# MYSQL Subquery and count number of rows containing a value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `oc_order o` and `oc_order_total ot`

`oc_order o` has fields `o.customer_id, o.date_added, o.email,o.total`

And `oc_order_total ot` has fields `ot.code` and `ot.value`

I want to show results only if  customer orders more than 3 times that is if `customer_id` repeats thrice or more in the result and  show `ot.value where ot.code = 'shipping'`

I am trying to do following

```
SELECT COUNT(o.customer_id) AS 'Orders Count', o.date_added, o.email,o.total, ot.value
FROM oc_order o
Inner join oc_order_total ot ON ot.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE count(o.customer_id) > 3 AND ot.value = (select value from oc_order_total where code = 'shipping' )
GROUP BY o.customer_id
```

I am getting Invalid use of group error and I think I am not using subquery correctly in where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `SUM`/`COUNT` in `WHERE` statement. You need to use for this `HAVING` operator. Try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(o.customer_id) AS 'Orders Count', o.date_added, o.email,o.total, ot.value

FROM oc_order o
INNER JOIN oc_order_total ot ON ot.order_id = o.order_id AND 

WHERE ot.code IN (select value from oc_order_total where code = 'shipping' )

GROUP BY o.customer_id
HAVING count(o.customer_id) > 3
```

EDIT: Adding example with ot.value not affected by `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT o.order_id, q.orders_count AS 'Orders Count', o.date_added, o.email,o.total, ot.value

FROM oc_order o
INNER JOIN oc_order_total ot ON ot.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT o.customer_id, COUNT(o.customer_id) AS orders_count

FROM oc_order o
INNER JOIN oc_order_total ot ON ot.order_id = o.order_id

WHERE ot.code IN (select value from oc_order_total where code = 'shipping' )

GROUP BY o.customer_id
HAVING count(o.customer_id) > 3) AS q ON q.customer_id = o.customer_id
```

Basically what happens here is that you pre-filter customers with previous query and then use these pre-filtered list to get individual orders for these customers meeting your criteria. On this individual `orders_id` you can perform any operation without grouping cause you already eliminated customers not meeting your needs. Hope it helps.

Comment: I was not doing group by as it would group it together and sum the amount and value together. I would want to show all the values. is it possible to do it without grouping it together?

Comment: You need `GROUP BY` to use `COUNT` or otherwise it will reduce it to one row grouping by default all rows regardless of your intention. However you could use a trick and wrap query with another `SELECT` to first get only o.order_id and after you have it filtered `JOIN` other necessary columns that they would not be affected by `GROUP BY`. Edited answer cause comment limit is too short to give you example.

Answer (score 1):

NO, you are getting error cause your `GROUP BY` doesn't contains all the column listed in `SELECT` list and you can't use `COUNT()` aggregate function like that in `WHERE` condition; it's only allowed in `HAVING` clause. You can modify your query like

```
SELECT o.date_added
     , o.email
     , o.total
     , ot.value
  FROM oc_order o
  JOIN oc_order_total ot 
    ON ot.order_id = o.order_id
  JOIN
     ( SELECT COUNT(customer_id) AS 'Orders Count'
            , customer_id
         FROM oc_order
        GROUP 
           BY customer_id 
     ) xxx 
    ON xxx .customer_id = o.customer_id
 WHERE  xxx.`Orders Count` > 3 
   AND ot.code = 'shipping';
```

Comment: @Strawberry, neither got your comment not the reason behind downvote?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, aggregates cannot be referenced in the WHERE clause.

The predicates in the WHERE clause are evaluated when the rows are accessed. At the time the rows are being retrieved, MySQL doesn't have any information about the value returned by aggregate functions (e.g. `COUNT()`).

The `COUNT()` aggregate will be evaluated *after* the rows are accessed, and after the `GROUP BY` operation.

An aggregate can be referenced in a `HAVING` clause, following the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
 GROUP BY ...
HAVING COUNT(...) > 3
```

Note that the HAVING clause is evaluated *after* the GROUP BY operation, and *after* the values of the aggregate expressions are evaluated. Much different than the WHERE clause.

---

Also, the subquery is a bit odd. Because it's being referenced in an equality comparison, the subquery can return at most one row. We don't see anything in the query that would prevent that, unless `code` is guaranteed to be unique in `ot_.

If `code` is unique, then we wouldn't need a subquery at all, we could just test for code.

```
 WHERE ot.code = 'shipping'
```

If there are multiple rows with "shipping" in the `code` column, we don't see any guarantee that the `value` column on those rows will be the same. To test for any of the possible values, we could use an `IN` operator instead of the equality (scalar) comparison. e.g.

```
 WHERE ot.value IN ( SELECT v.value 
                       FROM oc_order_total v
                      WHERE v.code = 'shipping'
                   )
```

But that still looks really odd. What's strange is that it's using the *same* table as the outer query. If we are using a subquery to lookup the set of `value`s related to a string `code`, that's usually a separate lookup table. And we'd normally prefer a `JOIN` operation rather than an `IN (subquery)`. Very strange.

---

Also, the non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list

```
 o.date_added, o.email, o.total, ot.value
```

Do not appear in the GROUP BY clause. Most relational databases will throw an error "non-aggregate in select not in group by" something of that ilk.

But a MySQL extension will allow the query to run, but the values returned for the non-aggregates is indeterminate. MySQL will return values for those expressions based on *some* row included in the collapsed set, but there's no guarantee which row that will be.

We can also get MySQL to throw an error like other databases, by including `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the `sql_mode` variable.